# JList ArrayList 3 items from each object

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have this method that sets my JList of days to each Day object in my ArrayList

```
public void setCalender(ArrayList<Day> calender) {
    this.calender = calender;
    listDays.setListData(this.calender.toArray());
}
```

Each day contains 3 Period objects. Currently the list renders as:

```
Day1
Day2
Day3
```

However I want the user to also be able to select a period, by rendering

```
Day1: Period1
Day1: Period2
Day1: Period3
Day2: Period1
Day3: Period2
Day3: Period3
```

..and so on. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would use 2 JList next to each other. When you select an item in the first list, the second one becomes active and displays the periods of the day selected in the first list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a method like `getPeriods()` which returns the period list of a specific day, you can use this code:

```
ArrayList<Day> calender;

ArrayList<Period> periods = new ArrayList<Period>();

for(Day d: calender)
{
   for(Period p : d.getPeriods())
   {
       periods.add(p);
   }
}
listDays.setListData(periods.toArray());
```

Comment: Using this method, won't it just write Period1, Period2, Period3, Period1, Period2, Period3?